# IntelliJ merge shows no content

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge

I have been working on a feature branch for quite some time and have also been merging the master into my branch every 2 days or so.

But recently someone changed 2 files on the master, that are also changed in my branch (conflict).

1. So for example I had **File1** and **File2** on master
2. Checked out the master and made 1 month of changes on that branch
3. On master **File1** and **File2** are changed slightly, but the file on master is significantly different to the one on my feature branch.

Now IntelliJ shows me a merge conflict, but I can't click merge. When I double-click on the file it opens up with the left and right pane completely empty and in the middle there is my new version. I can't merge and everything I do does not get saved. The only thing I can do is manually revert the merge in the Local Changes tab.

Here is the merge conflict (bottom two files are the ones in question)
[image]

Here is the 3 pane merge resolve window (Middle pane is full of code - a few hundred lines):
[image]

Also, tried Tortoise Git, but there I can only find the automatic merge, but that does not work either (Same problem).

What do you think, I should do?

*I am not able to show screenshots, because it is code that I do not own personally.*

Comment: Open this file in IDEA. Conflicts will be marked with `>>>>>` and `<<<<<` symbols.
Resolve conflicts manually and then add them to staged changes and then merge. If it would not help, try to add screen shot with blurred code or sth.

Comment: @Rumid Added screenshots

Comment: IntelliJ requests contents for the merge dialog from git index. E.g. `git cat-file -p 1:<path\to\file>` for the initial state of the central pane. Such an issue could be a bug or git integration misconfiguration in IntelliJ. Actually, it is worth reporting the issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with logs attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar problem. In my case, and [the original question's case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571497/intellij-merge-shows-no-content#comment101605301_57572171) as well, the problem was a casing change (e.g., capital to small) in the file pathname.

This is how I resolved it:

- Use IntelliJ merge as usual (using the commandline didn't make a difference).
- See the files that have this problem.
- Close the "Resolve Conflicts" tool and go change the casing of these files manually*.
- After you do that, from IntelliJ menu "VCS -> Git -> Resolve Conflicts". You should see the problematic files returned to normal. Resolve the conflicts and close.
- In the normal case, IntelliJ would've created the merge commit for you. But it seems like it doesn't when you close the "Resolve Conflicts" tool and re-open it. So, from the commandline run `git merge --continue` to finish the merge.

*Note: For how to know what the casing has been changed to, I'm not sure. In my case, it was from the `package ...`

And I guess the problem is with Windows Filesystem API being case-insensitive or something...

**Update:** In my case, there was a new file that referenced a file that used the old casing. Although I changed it, it wasn't included in the merge commit. Not sure of the reason. But anyway, if this happens, solve it manually by creating a new commit or amending the last one.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the problem I have been facing. I mentioned it in the comments of the original answer, but as your answer seems to be more detailed about solving the problem, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

set your default editor to whatever you want for example:
`git config --global editor.core "gedit"`
Then set the merge tool as that editor and resolve it on your editor, do all this from the command line, I find the cli simpler and smoother then intelliJ in many cases.

Comment: Thanks I tried it, but with your settings in Git bash I get this error `CONFLICT <filename> deleted in HEAD and modified in master`. How can I fix this now?

Comment: When I navigate to the folder of that file, the original file is there (untouched, meaning no `>>>>>>>` or `<<<<<<<<<<`), but the same file exists again with the same name and a `~master` appended at the end.

Comment: Sounds like you may have accidentally deleted the file, try going back a few commits and see what happened, you can get a full log of what happened with `git reflog`

Comment: I just saw that there was a name change in the casing. So basically it are two different files now, called the exact same, but having a different casing than the other. How can I resolve this. (Example: on master: TESTFile1 and on feature: TestFile1)

Comment: abort the merge, do the whole thing again from the cli. Alternatively change the file name then force push (try option a first)

Comment: I deleted the files on master and then it worked. Thanks!